# Boost::Asio - Should I let io_context::run thread exit?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am developing a asynchronous client TCP program using boost::asio. I have question regarding accepted practice : In case if socket breaks or disconnects should I let my io_context thread exit (i.e. not issue any async_connect request and let my run method exit) and let main thread restart io_context and attempt async_connect or should I give async_connect request to stop my io_context thread from exiting (i.e. issue any async_connect request and not let my run method exit). Which approach is more acceptable.

As per my assumption the advantage of letting io_context thread exit is that you start with a new clean thread (you start with new slate) and downside is more computation, resource requirement and execution time.

On the contrary if continue with my current io_context thread i.e. I give async_connect request to stop my io_context thread from exiting I save on computation, resource requirement and execution time but I don't get clean slate.

Which of the two method is more advisable?

```
void AsyncSocket::recieveHandler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    fmt::print("In recieve handler, Error Code : {}\nBytes recieved : {}\n", ec.message(), bytes_transferred);
    try
    {
        std::atomic_store(std::addressof(this->receivingData), false);
        if (ec not_eq boost::system::errc::success)
        {
#ifdef _DEBUG
            fmt::print("Error in WebSocket::recieveHandler. Error : {0}\n", ec.message());
#endif // _DEBUG
            LOG_ERROR << ec.message();
            switch (ec.value())
            {
            case boost::asio::error::eof :
            case boost::asio::error::connection_reset :
            case boost::asio::error::connection_aborted :
            case boost::asio::error::network_reset :
            case boost::asio::error::network_down :
            case boost::asio::error::network_unreachable :
                if (this->isSocketAlive() and this->socket.is_open())
                    this->socket.close();
                std::atomic_store(std::addressof(this->socketAlive), false);
                //this->connectSocket(); //[1]
                return;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            this->readDataQueue.push(std::string(reinterpret_cast <const char *> (this->readDataBuffer.data()), bytes_transferred));
            std::atomic_store(std::addressof(this->readComplete), true);
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        fmt::print("Error in WebSocket::sendHandler. Error : {0}\n", ex.what());
#endif // _DEBUG
        LOG_ERROR << "Exception : " << ex.what() << "Data : " << this->writeDataQueue.front();
    }
    this->recieveDataSocket();
}
```

Commenting 1 lets the io_context thread exit and un-commenting stops io_context thread from being exited.

Comment: If you want to use a thread to maintain the state of a single connection, then you don't need async io in the first place, that's what blocked io is for. In async io, thread is only to execute io operation, it contains multiple connection states at the same time.

Comment: @liliscent, Sir I understand your point but I find asynchronous IO in socket more convenient than synchronous model. I am also trying to get hands-on experience on asynchronous IO model before my application is scaled up to multiple devices.